# Filling a character array or a string - looking for a better way

Tags: c#, printing

I have a written a very simple C# code that performs the following task:

given a number `n` which represents amount of spaces, my program will print the hourglass:

```
*****
 ***
  *
 ***
*****
```

Beginning `n` spaces from the left boundary wall of the command window.

My code works as intended, but it is very very messy, disorganized, and I am sure there is a better way, perhaps something that was previously implemented in C# by microsoft developers who developed the .NET Framework.

This is my code:

```
public static void printAsterisk(int initialSpace)
{
    int i, j;
    char[] asteriskMsg = new char[5 * initialSpace + 25];
    for (i = 0; i < initialSpace; i++)
    {
        asteriskMsg[i] = ' ';
    }
    for (j = i; j < i + 5; j++)
    {
        asteriskMsg[j] = '*';
    }
    asteriskMsg[j] = '\n';
    for (i = j + 1; i < j + initialSpace + 1; i++)
    {
        asteriskMsg[i] = ' ';
    }
    for (j = i + 1; j < i + 4; j++)
    {
        asteriskMsg[j] = '*';
    }
    asteriskMsg[j] = '\n';
    for (i = j + 1; i < j + initialSpace + 3; i++)
    {
        asteriskMsg[i] = ' ';
    }
    asteriskMsg[i] = '*';
    asteriskMsg[i + 1] = '\n';
    for (j = i + 2; j < i + initialSpace + 3; j++)
    {
        asteriskMsg[j] = ' ';
    }
    for (i = j; i < j + 3; i++)
    {
        asteriskMsg[i] = '*';
    }
    asteriskMsg[i] = '\n';
    for (j = i + 1; j < i + initialSpace + 1; j++)
    {
        asteriskMsg[j] = ' ';
    }
    for (i = j; i < j + 5; i++)
    {
        asteriskMsg[i] = '*';
    }
    string s = new string(asteriskMsg);
    System.Console.Write("{0}", s);
}
```

}

It is quite horrifying. I am very curious as to how to improve this code.
Just to show an example of what I mean, this is how the program runs with `n=25`
[image]

If n was zero, then you would have seen the same picture but starting from the left wall, rather than with 25 spaces. I hope it is clear now what I am trying to do.

Edit: Managed to come up with a great solution myself using strings!

```
public static void printAsterisk(int initialSpace)
{
    string firstRow = "*****", secondRow = "***", thirdRow = "*", firstRowSpaces = new string(' ', initialSpace), secondRowSpaces = new string(' ', initialSpace+1), thirdRowSpaces = new string(' ', initialSpace+2);
    string hourglass = string.Format("{0}{1}\n{2}{3}\n{4}{5}\n{2}{3}\n{0}{1}", firstRowSpaces, firstRow, secondRowSpaces, secondRow, thirdRowSpaces, thirdRow);
    System.Console.WriteLine(hourglass);
}
```

Comment: are you familiar with the `new string()` overload you want `10 *` for example you can do `var fiveDelim = new string('*',5);`

Comment: With all due respect @Peter Duniho I don't think the question you've marked that duplicates this really answers the question asked. It was asking how to print an hourglass given n levels not necessarily just how to repeat the same character a specified number of times. Oria here is a fiddle I knocked up doing what you want it to do https://dotnetfiddle.net/qg5zbf

Comment: It's not my most elegant work, but I had fun. Please excuse the formatting issues, I wrote this on my mobile and there's no easy way to indent! https://ideone.com/n06Nmw

Comment: @ZacBraddy: if the OP wants the whole implementation of the entire problem (i.e. a full-blown rewrite of their code), then the question is too broad. The title of the question reads _"Filling a character array or a string"_, which is clearly a duplicate of the marked question.

Comment: Thank you all, managed to come up with a clever solution (I think so at least) myself. Thanks to everyone.

Comment: @oria-gruber Thanks for the fun question :)

Comment: @zac-braddy your hour glass' resolution is better than ours' :)

Comment: How about defining the hourglass size as well? https://ideone.com/n06Nmw

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I liked this question :)

This is my way of doing it. Really expecting others, since this is really fun :)

```
public class Program
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        PrintHourGlass(25);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Prints an hour glass starting at the given offset
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="indent">The starting offset</param>
    static void PrintHourGlass(int indent)
    {
        PrintAsteriks(indent, 5); // offset = indent, print 5 *          [I]*****
        PrintAsteriks(indent + 1, 3); // offset = indent + 1, print 3 *  [I] ***
        PrintAsteriks(indent + 2, 1); // offset = indent +3, print 1 *   [I]  *
        PrintAsteriks(indent + 1, 3); // offset = indent + 1, print 3 *  [I] ***
        PrintAsteriks(indent, 5); // offset = indent, print 5 *          [I]*****
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Prints given number of * characters starting from the given offset
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="indent">The starting offset</param>
    /// <param name="asterisks">The number of * characters to print</param>
    static void PrintAsteriks(int indent, int asterisks)
    {
        // Check starters guide to string.Format here:
        // https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.format(v=vs.110).aspx#Starting

        // string format uses a template and allows you to pass in and format arguments as you like.
        // The template below evaluates to {0,25}{1} for indent = 25 and asteriks = 5
        // which means,
        // print argument 0 (first parameter), no extra formatting, pad the output to 25 characters
        // print argument 1, no formatting
        string formatString = "{0," + indent + "}{1}";

        // Console.WriteLine method uses string.Format internally
        // Below, for the template, argument 0 is null
        //     (since we want to print only 25 characters, the padding.
        //     The value could have been "" instead of null)
        // Argument 1 is a string of * characters, with the length specified by asteriks parameter
        Console.WriteLine(formatString, null, new string('*', asterisks));

        // Therefore, it outputs 25 linear white spaces, then 5 * characters.
    }
}
```

Comment: That's great, but I am very new to C#. Could you explain to me please how this works?

Comment: Of course. I am adding comments to the source code now.

Comment: @oria-gruber it's done.

Comment: Thanks! I also managed to think of a solution. Please check the edits :)